# How do I point two urls to the same child site in a multisite config

Tags: multisite, redirect, urls

I did not see a solution among your current posts... One of our child sites (newengland.nfoic.net) has a URL (nefirstamendment.org) pointed to it and is recorded as such in the admin using the site ID number and with Primary site checked. I want to point another URL NEFAC.org to the site and want to know how to accomplish that. I added the site on the back-end with the same ID but cannot mark as Primary as neither site will display it. What do I need to do besides:
Redirect the nefac.org A record to the multi site domain
Change the DNS servers from where the nefac.org url is registered
Add the nefac.org as a new site on my (cloud) host admin?

Right now we just see a Coming Soon page for nefac.org. Thank you. Daniel

Comment: Which plugin you are using for domain mapping?

Comment: Nikolay - WordPress MU Domain Mapping. Thank you for your question.

Answer (score 0):

Don't add more sites to point more domains to the same site. Just add more domains to the same site from this address **/wp-admin/tools.php?page=domainmapping** of the dashboard of the site.

You might need to disable primary domain check from this network admin page **/wp-admin/network/settings.php?page=dm_admin_page** if you don't want the domains to all redirect to the primary one.

For support about the domain mapping plugin, you should go here: https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping

Comment: Many thanks Nikolay. I'll follow your recommendations. Great help!

Comment: @DanielBevarly Great. If it worked and this solved your issue, please accept the answer as a solution, so it is visible for everyone that this topic does not need more attention. Regards.